# Java JTextPane Change Font of Selected Text

Tags: java, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane  (or JEditorPane, I can use either no problem).  How can I change the font of a selected area to a specific font?

`textpane.getSelectedText().setFont()` won't work.  (Even with font-family)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<s>You can change JTextPane's font only as a whole, it doesn't do rich text.</s>

There's a `Document` underneath JEditorPane (and apparently JTextPane too), which you get a hold of with `getDocument()`. You want to cast that to a `StyledDocument` if you can, and then you can do things like `setCharacterAttributes` to a given run of characters.

There are some (hopefully) helpful examples in the Java tutorial at http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html .

Comment: +1, for referring to the tutorial. I wish more people would do this as it answers the immediate question and provides a resource for future questions.

Comment: And put us out of business? (laugh) But I agree, the Tutorial is underrated, it taught me much of what I know. Alas, some sections seem to be put together a bit hastily: The RMI tutorial still has me confused today. Thanks for the vote!

Comment: (to be fair, 95% of the tutorial is GREAT!)

Comment: javax.swing.text.StyleConstants.setFontFamily only accepts a "String" as input to the "font-family". is there anyway we can use custom fonts ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using JTextPane. It is impossible to do this using JTextArea. . Here is a best example on how to use JTextPane.

Sample: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html

Code: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextSamplerDemoProject/src/components/TextSamplerDemo.java

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.