# How can my JTextPane display multiple fonts?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextpane, styleddocument

I'm trying to design a part of a bigger GUI that will format some text to look good. It should be able to play with text in a lot of funny ways. Adding borders, underlining, i.e anything I could want to do with text for decorative purposes. Is JTextPane the way to go for this purpose?

In my example below I want `decorateTextPane()` to display two lines of text with different font. But whenever I call `textPane.setFont()` I change the font of all existing text in the pane.

```
public class OuterClass {
    InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();

    private class InnerClass {
        private JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane()

        public InnerClass() {
            StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
            SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
            StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
            doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
        }
    }

    public void decorateTextPane() {
        inner.textPane.setFont(New Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        inner.textPane.setText("First string");
        inner.textPane.setFont(New Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 15));
        inner.textPane.append("\nSecond string"); //my textPane class defines an append method.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining the `useFont()` methods and using them before adding the text that should use its specified font is my current approach. It's working and I'm content, but if anyone have any better answers I'm still very interested :-)

```
public class OuterClass {
InnerClass inner = new InnerClass();

private class InnerClass {
    private JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
    private Font firstFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.PLAIN, 18);
    private Font secondFont = new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14);
    StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
    SimpleAttributeSet aSet = new SimpleAttributeSet();

    public InnerClass() {
        StyledDocument doc = textPane.getStyledDocument();
        SimpleAttributeSet center = new SimpleAttributeSet();
        StyleConstants.setAlignment(center, StyleConstants.ALIGN_CENTER);
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, doc.getLength(), center, false);
    }

    public void useFont1() {
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(aSet, firstFont.getFamily());
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(aSet, firstFont.getSize());
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(0, 0, aSet, false);
    }

    public void useFont2() {
        StyleConstants.setFontFamily(aSet, secondFont.getFamily());
        StyleConstants.setFontSize(aSet, secondFont.getSize());
        doc.setParagraphAttributes(doc.getLength(), 0, aSet, false);
    }
}

public void decorateTextPane() {
    inner.useFont1();
    inner.textPane.setText("First string");
    inner.useFont2();
    inner.textPane.append("\nSecond string"); //my textPane class defines an append method.
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use a  `JEditorPane` instead of a `JTextPane` because it is well-suited for the task you want to accomplish. :)

From the answer  [Java JTextPane Change Font of Selected Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905461/java-jtextpane-change-font-of-selected-text)

There's a `Document` underneath JEditorPane (and apparently JTextPane too), which you get a hold of with `getDocument()`. You want to cast that to a `StyledDocument` if you can, and then you can do things like `setCharacterAttributes` to a given run of characters.

Examples : http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html