# changing font size for specific text in jtextpane

Tags: java

Ok, I am writing a text editor using a JTextPane. I am trying to figure out how to change the font size for specific text that the user types in. I have a JButton that the user can click to bring up a font-size and font-type selection menu. When the user selects the proper font size and type and presses ok, I then proceed to get the font size and type inside a `Font`. All I need to do now is to set the `Font` of the selected text in the JTextPane without overriding the current style(s) of the text. I haven't found anything that enables me to do this. Maybe I just missed something somewhere...

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am a newbie on StackOverFlow so please edit my question if I did something wrong.

Comment: try to use the function setFont. more information in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10585956/jtextpane-how-to-set-the-font-size

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905461/java-jtextpane-change-font-of-selected-text there's a similar question.

Comment: `textpane.setFont(font);` where textpane = jtextpane; and font = java.awt.Font[family=Serif,name=Serif,style=plain,size=20] doesn't work for me...

Comment: @CoderDudeTwodee in that answer you get the styled document and then add a style that contains the selected text to where the selected text is, I figured out how to do that, but it still erases all previous styles...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a styled editor kit and fire the actions inside the actionperformed method.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried with this.

replaceSelection()

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextPane.html#replaceSelection(java.lang.String)

Comment: I have tried this, the problem with this is you have to getSelectedText and save it as a String. when I do that, I lose all previous styles of text. Is there a way to getSelectedText and save it with all current styles and then "overwrite" any styles I need to?